# Dúvida no uso do Socket em java no android

Tags: java, android, socket.io

Quero implementar transmissão de dados via Socket, estou tentando implementar Socket.io mas não entendo o funcionamento.
Quero fazer a comunicação entre dois dispositivos android. Sei que tem a parte do servidor e cliente. Mas não consigo entender se há necessidade de um servidor web (dispositivo > server > dispositivo) ou eles se comunicam apenas entre si (dispositivo > dispositivo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar aparelhos se comunicarem ponto a ponto, sem problemas. Só precisa ter em mente que: deve existir um aparelho que será tratado como servidor, ou seja, quem vai ficar escutando uma conexão direta.
E o segundo aparelho é o cliente, ou seja, quem vai se conectar ao servidor.

Obs.: construa o Server socket e cliente socket em threads para não travar a ui dos aparelhos.

Código rudimentar de como poderia ser o socket:

Cliente Side

```
try {
            String SERVER_SOCKET = "127.0.0.1";
            int SERVER_PORT = 8989;
            Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_SOCKET, SERVER_PORT);

            String inputLine;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()) );

            while( (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ){
                Log.d("socketcst", "Recebendo dados do servidor" );
                Log.d("socketcst", inputLine );
            }

            Log.d("socketcst", "Connectou ao servidor");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d("socketcst", "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("socketcst", "IOException: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d("socketcst", "Fechou a conexão com o servidor");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("socketcst", "IOException - Close: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Server Side

```
private String host = "192.168.0.31";
    private int port = 8989;
    private int conexoes =  50;

    Socket socket = new Socket(this.port, this.conexoes);
    InetAddress inet = socket.getInetAddress();     
    System.out.println("Servidor iniciado na porta " + this.port );

    while (!socket.isClosed()) {

        socket.accept();

        try {

            InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            OutputStreamWriter saida = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(saida);

            String inputLine;   
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( entrada );
            JSONObject dadosEntrada = null;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("socketcst", inputLine );
             }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }  
    }

    socket.close();
```

Todo o codigo deve ser rodado como serviçoou threads para não bloquear a aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado Mauricio, por me esclarecer essa dúvida. Vou fazer isso.

Comment: Inclusive a alguns dias fiz algo bem desse gênero

Comment: Então eu uso o IP de cada dispositivo?

Comment: Só vai importar o IP e a porta do socket servidor, no caso o IP atual do celular que vai ser o Server e a porta que ele.vais disponibilizar para conexao. O cliente deve se conectar no IP e porta específica do socket server

Comment: Acredito que o que ele queira criar como se fosse uma transmissão P2P entre os aparelhos. Além disso, poderia ter um trecho de código explicando o funcionamento.